# pragma export function is not external in Ada executable

Tags: windows, dll, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I need a Visual Studio C++ DLL be able to call a function in my Ada mainline.  The Ada code has a function spec like

```
package offset is
    function GET_OFFSET return integer;
    pragma Export (Stdcall, GET_OFFSET, "fnAdaOffset");
end offset;
```

The C++ function then would call the Ada method as follows:

```
typedef int (*tdAdaOffset)(void);
tdAdaOffset _ptAdaOffset = NULL;

int AdaOffset()
{
   if (_ptAdaOffset == NULL)
   {
      _ptAdaOffset = (tdAdaOffset)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "fnAdaOffset@0");
      if (_ptAdaOffset == NULL)
         throw "Function not found";
   }
   return (*_ptAdaOffset)();
}
```

I believe this would work.  The problem I have is that Ada refuses to mark the function GET_OFFSET as external in the executable, i.e. doing dumpbin /exports ada.exe shows me no exported functions.

I've read various solutions such as [--version-script for the linker](http://anadoxin.org/blog/control-over-symbol-exports-in-gcc.html) , but my linker seems too old to know about this switch.

Another promising option was to add -shared to the link step, but while this now exposes the functions, it also changes the output file to a DLL (with .EXE as its extension (!)), so that's not useful either.

Before I upgrade my toolchain, is there another linker switch I can try, or any other suggestions?

Comment: I believe you need `-Wl,--export-dynamic` to export a function from an executable, but I have never done that.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `Stdcall` in Ada if you don't specify `__stdcall` in C++.

Comment: One question I have that might affect answers for this question is how does initialization/finalization play a role in this.  Normally when using an Ada DLL in C++ you have to bind and use an initialization routine before calling Ada routines and sometimes call a bound finalization routine after.  I feel like this might apply here, but not sure how specifically since the Author didn't specify if this was Ada calling c++ DLL calling Ada routine vs C++ calling C++ DLL calling Ada routine

Comment: @flyx, you were almost there: the correct switch when creating an EXE was ```-Wl,-export-all-symbols```.  I had to upgrade to a newer version of GNATGPL to use it. Submit as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @Jere, since my mainline is written in Ada, all the elaboration will be done by the time I'm calling the Visual C++ routine which in turn will call back into Ada. Thanks for reminder though.

Comment: @erict Great! Found some additional info and distilled it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the linker to export the symbols from the executable. `ld` has an option `--export-dynamic`, however that [only works on ELF targets](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> Note that this option is specific to ELF targeted ports. PE targets support a similar function to export all symbols from a DLL or EXE ; see the description of --export-all-symbols below.

Therefore, on Windows, you need to use `--export-all-symbols`.

Depending on how you compile your Ada code, you may need to pass this option through the compiler command (`gcc`). To tell `gcc` that an option is to be consumed by the linker, you prefix it with `-Wl` and then give the linker options separated by commas. In this case, you would end up with `-Wl,--export-all-symbols`.

If you're using GPRBuild, the relevant part of your `.gpr` file would look like this:

```vhdl
package Linker is
  for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-Wl,--export-all-symbols");
end Linker;
```

---

Side notes:

- Be aware that C++'s `int` is not necessarily the same as Ada's `Integer` and you should use `Interfaces.C.int` for the return type in Ada instead.
- Calling conventions must match. `Stdcall` in Ada matches an explicit `__stdcall` in C++. If you don't have `__stdcall` in the C++ code, use the `C` calling convention in Ada instead.